# Vector Line Integral For Biot Savart Law

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, line-integrals, electromagnetism

How would one go about computing the vector line integral presented in the Biot-Savart law: $$\vec{B}=\int_c\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi} \frac{d\vec{l}\times\hat{r}}{r^2}$$
I know how to compute vector line integrals: $\int_c\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s} = \int_a^b\vec{F}(\vec{r}(t))\cdot (\vec{r}(t))'dt$, but I have no idea where to start with the above integral. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @TedShifrin that's what I'm struggling to figure out...

Comment: The difference here is the answer is a vector rather than a scalar. What line integral is the $\hat i$-component of that vector?

Comment: @TedShifrin so how would I go about solving this?

Comment: Exactly the same way : choose a parametrization $\vec{l}(t)$ for the line $c$, hence $\mathrm{d}\vec{l} = \vec{l'}\mathrm{d}t$.